# Install Eclipse 3.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ide, installation, ubuntu-10.10

I am new to linux, I have download the eclipse 3.6 linux version fron eclipse web site. can someone explains me how to install it on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just unpack it. There should be an executable called eclipse. Just run that.

Comment: I am clicking on it , i am getting an error message sayigng Could not display "/home/noor/Desktop/eclipse-S...6.1-linux-gtk/eclipse/eclipse".There is no application installed for executable files

Comment: Can you run it from the commandline?

Comment: how to do so, i am used to windows and mac and now i need to use linux so i don't know how to do this in linux, i'm googling but not getting any proper result

Comment: open terminal and then type /home/noor/Desktop/eclipse-S...6.1-linux-gtk/eclipse/eclipse and hit enter.

Comment: it works, it was simple but since i am not that aquanted to linux, to was really hard for me, i spent more than 1 hr with this, thanks lots!!

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to ensure java is installed on your Ubuntu.

Comment: I've a fresh ubuntu install, and I'm totally new at Linux. How does one insure everything is installed.  I get a message that says Java isn't installed, but when I attempt to install java  (the bin) it seems to unpack correctly.  Is it installed.